# Jsonschema strict array values to root key names

Tags: json, jsonschema

Data sample:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "depends_on": []
  },
  "bar": {
    "depends_on": ["foo"]
  }
}
```

Current schema:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^.+$": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "depends_on": {
          "type": "array"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What change on schema is needed to depends_on only contains keys name of root object except themselves parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Schema cannot express that constraint.